# PropertyInfo.SetValue ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following code. However, it has a runtime exception on `SetValue`. What may cause the error?

```
var _filter = new Filter(....); // Filter implemented IFilter
ApplyFilter(_view.Name, x => x.Name); 

private void ApplyFilter<T>(T curr, Expression<Func<IFilter, T>> prev) 
{
    var expr = (MemberExpression)prev.Body;
    var prop = (PropertyInfo)expr.Member;
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(curr, (T)_filter[prop.Name]))
    {
        prop.SetValue(_filter, curr, null); // Error
        ..... // do something on _filter
```

The exception is:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Property set method not found.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
       at MyApp.ErrorLogPresenter.ApplyFilter[T](T curr, Expression`1 prev) in d:\....cs:line 50
```

Comment: Please post the exception too.

Comment: ignoring the index on an indexing property [] or trying to set a property that only has a getter...

Comment: "Property set method not found." - sounds pretty clear to me; does this property have a setter? Can we see the property in question?

Comment: @AK_ The row raises exception doesn't use indexer?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks very much. I forgot the interface doesn't define setter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Message=Property set method not found.
```

This usually simply means that the property you are using *does not define a setter*. Either ensure that a suitable setter exists, or use a different approach to assign values.